# C language. TCP server-client, string passing error

Tags: c, tcp, client-server

I have a problem with passing string as the argument to my client, and I new to C so can't really figure out what is going on. I managed to pass a character to server, but got problem with strings. This code represents the main loop from my Server:

```
while(1)
{
    char ch[256];
    printf("server waiting\n");

    rc = read(client_sockfd, &ch, 1); 
    printf("The message is: %s\n", ch);
    write(client_sockfd, &ch, 1);
    break;
}
```

The client code:

```
 char ch[256] = "Test";

 rc = write(sockfd, &ch, 1);
```

The message printed by server is the following:

[image]

Can someone give me a hand with this.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your buffer ch[] is not null terminated.  And because you are only reading 1 byte at a time, the rest of that buffer is garbage chars. Also, you are using passing &ch to the read call, but arrays are already pointers, so &ch == ch.

At the very least the code needs to look like this:

```
    rc = read(client_sockfd, ch, 1); 
    if (rc >= 0)
    {
       ch[rc] = '\0';
    }
```

But that will only print one character at a time since you are only reading one byte a time.  this will be better:

```
while(1)
{
    char buffer[256+1]; // +1 so we can always null terminate the buffer appropriately and safely before printing.
    printf("server waiting\n");

    rc = read(client_sockfd, buffer, 256);
    if (rc <= 0)
    {
        break; // error or remote socket closed
    }
    buffer[rc] = '\0';

    printf("The message is: %s\n", buffer); // this should print the buffer just fine
    write(client_sockfd, buffer, rc); // echo back exactly the message that was just received

    break; // If you remove this line, the code will continue to fetch new bytes and echo them out
}
```